# normalise list data in range (0.0, 1.0)

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I create a dict with lists as values, containing some parameters. these parameters are mostly float or int and sometimes boolean values (in my case stored as 0 or 1). Now i want to select the best entry of the dict (= which has the highest parameters)

for this reason i need to normalise the parameters, so that every parameter is only in the range of 0...1. 
a naive way would be to create a list of max values for every list "column" and then divide all values by this max value:

```
import heapq

a = {1: [1.0, 23.7, 17.5, 0.2],
     2: [0.0, 87.3, 11.2, 0.5],
     3: [1.0, 17.4, 15.2, 0.7]}

ran = len(a.values()[0])

max = [0.0 for i in range(0,ran)]

for vals in a.values():
    max = [max[x] if max[x] > vals[x] else vals[x] for x in range(0,ran)]

a = {k : [v[x]/max[x] for x in range(0,ran)] for k,v in a.items()}

best = heapq.nlargest(1, (v for v in a.values()), key=lambda v: sum(v))

print a
print best
```

which seems to work here, but is there any optimization i can take from here? The dicts i have to deal with will contain over 1000 entries, and the parameters will be in the range of 20 to 50.
also i need to do this on about 1000 sets of dicts, so a fast approach would be help a lot.

edit: i tested it now with generated data:

```
import heapq
import random

def normalise(a):
    ran = len(a.values()[0])

    max = [0.0 for i in range(0,ran)]

    for vals in a.values():
        max = [max[x] if max[x] > vals[x] else vals[x] for x in range(0,ran)]

    a = {k : [v[x]/max[x] for x in range(0,ran)] for k,v in a.items()}

# find best list
    best = heapq.nlargest(1, (v for v in a.values()), key=lambda v: sum(v))


# test this 1000 times 
for _ in xrange(1000):
    a = { k: [1000.0*random.random() for i in xrange(50)] for k in xrange(1000)} 
    normalise(a)
```

and got the following result:

```
25,84s user 0,02s system 49% cpu 52,189 total, running python normalise.py
```

Comment: With those kinds of numbers, it sounds as if you want to use `numpy` data sets instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do straight loops over the dict and handle each list directly:

```
from operator import itemgetter

best = (0, [])
maxes = [max(c) for c in zip(*a.values())]
for k, v in a.iteritems():
    v = a[k] = [c/m for c, m in zip(v, maxes)]
    best = max([best, (sum(v), v)], key=itemgetter(0))
```

This uses `zip(*iterable)` to loop through the *columns* of `a`. We then normalize each row against the maximum per column, and pick out the best row at the same time.

Note that `heapq.nlargest(1, ...)` just uses `max` instead, as that'd be the more efficient approach.

Timings, measured with the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), against the original sample:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> import heapq
>>> def original(a):
...     ran = len(a.values()[0])
...     max = [0.0 for i in range(0,ran)]
...     for vals in a.values():
...         max = [max[x] if max[x] > vals[x] else vals[x] for x in range(0,ran)]
...     a = {k : [v[x]/max[x] for x in range(0,ran)] for k,v in a.items()}
...     best = heapq.nlargest(1, (v for v in a.values()), key=lambda v: sum(v))
... 
>>> def zip_and_max(a):
...     best = (0, [])
...     maxes = [max(c) for c in zip(*a.values())]
...     for k, v in a.iteritems():
...         v = a[k] = [c/m for c, m in zip(v, maxes)]
...         best = max([best, (sum(v), v)], key=itemgetter(0))
... 
>>> timeit('f(a.copy())', 'from __main__ import a, original as f', number=100000)
2.6306018829345703
>>> timeit('f(a.copy())', 'from __main__ import a, zip_and_max as f', number=100000)
1.6974060535430908
```

and with one randomized set:

```
>>> import random
>>> random_a = { k: [1000.0*random.random() for i in xrange(50)] for k in xrange(1000)}
>>> timeit('f(a.copy())', 'from __main__ import a, original as f', number=100000)
2.7121059894561768
>>> timeit('f(a.copy())', 'from __main__ import a, zip_and_max as f', number=100000)
1.745398998260498
```

and with a randomized set each time (note, much lower repeat count):

```
>>> timeit('f(r())', 'from __main__ import random_dict as r, original as f', number=100)
4.437845945358276
>>> timeit('f(r())', 'from __main__ import random_dict as r, zip_and_max as f', number=100)
3.2406938076019287
```

But it sounds like you are processing matrices here. You need to look into `numpy` for a *far* more efficient library to process matrices like these.

Comment: without the zip it was faster: 19.33s vs 27.88 with zip.

Comment: @reox: I get faster times with your original sample, will re-time with a random set as well.

Answer (score 1):

That is all:

```
key, best = max(a.iteritems(), key = lambda t: sum(t[1])/max(t[1]))
```

Comment: and how you would generate the max list?

Comment: Is not your purpose to select the best entry of the dict? Then your have it.